# how to paste from byobu's screen buffer (ubuntu 12.04 64bit)

Tags: gnu-screen, byobu

I'm running byobu in gnome-terminal, under ubuntu 12.04 64bit.
and trying to copy a screen buffer.

i.e. 
by hitting F7, byobu entering "copy mode",
then mark screen text by space key.

the question is, how to paste those text after it copied those text into it's screen buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in case anyone need the answer,
after google around, I found the solution below.

the short answer is : ctrl-A ]

A longer answer:
to save the text into a file, open a text editor,
such as vim, set it to paste mode ( :set paste ), then input mode ( i ),
then paste it from byobu: ctrl-A ]
done!

Comment: Nothing happens when I do that.  But I'm not sure I'm actually getting anything into the "screen buffer", even though I do what the OP says: F7, space bar, move on screen (thus highlighting text).  So can you expand this to clarify how I copy the text in the first place?  I'm doing this on Ubuntu trusty in tmux / byobu.

Comment: did you see "copied ? chars into buffer" message from byobu ?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  No, I don't see "copied ? chars into buffer", and I don't know when I would see it.  I just move the mouse, and the highlighted region expands.  I do see "[0/1085]" in the upper right after I hit F7, but the 0 never changes.  So I'm assuming there is something I have to hit to get it to "copy", but I haven't found out what that is.  Lots of other keys do wild things, highlighting rectangular regions etc - what is the name for this F7 mode and where is it documented?

Comment: You should not use mouse, use your keyboard to control the terminal. after F7 (enter copy mode), hit first space key to start marking what text you want (with up/down/right/left/page-up/pg-down key), then hit 2nd space key to finish the marking. The text copy buffer will copied when 2nd space key. you should able to paste the copy buffer into an editor with ctrl-A + ] .

Comment: Hitting space a second time doesn't work for me.  But hitting enter does, as I finally found on the byobu man page at "SCROLLBACK, COPY, PASTE MODES": http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/byobu.1.html

Answer (score 1):

After the <kbd>Enter</kbd>, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>.